# Function that create a directory and an unlimited number of subdirectories

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion

My aim is to create a function, from a list corresponding to directories and subdirectories.

For example : 'reports/English' corresponds to the subdirectory 'English' in the directory 'reports'.

Here's my function :

```
for i in lst:
  splitted = i.split('/')
  if not os.path.exists(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0]) : 
    os.mkdir(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0])
    os.mkdir(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0] + '\\' + splitted[1])
  else :
    os.mkdir(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0] + '\\' + splitted[1])
```

I don't want to use the function os.chdir out of fear of losing myself in the folders.

I'd like to do a recursive function, I tried this :

```
def my_sub_function(splitted):
"""
"""
if splitted == []:
    return None

else:
    if not os.path.exists(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0]) : 
        os.mkdir(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0])
        os.mkdir(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0] + '\\' + splitted[1])
    else :
        os.mkdir(destination_directory + '\\' + splitted[0] + '\\' + splitted[1])
        return t1(splitted[1:])
```

So, consider this list :

```
lst_1 = 

['music',
 'reports/English',
 'reports/Spanish',
 'videos',
 'pictures/family',
 'pictures/party']
```

if I do :

```
it will creates these directories :
.\\music
.\\reports\\English
.\\reports\\Spanish
.\\videos
.\\pictures\\family
.\\pictures\\party
```

But I'm limited to on directory and only one sub_directory.
I'd like for my function to handle 3 or 4 subdirectories so that it could create something like this :

```
.\\pictures\\family\\Christmas\\meal\\funny
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what "it does not work" means? What is it doing?

Comment: Are you just looking for [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness of my post, I hope it is more explicit now

Comment: I have to manage to do it without os.makedirs() #schoolwork

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion necessarily, just a simple directory walk:

```
import os

def create_path(path):
    current_path = "."  # start with the current path
    segments = os.path.split(path)  # split the path into segments
    for segment in segments:
        candidate = os.path.join(current_path, segment)  # get the candidate
        if not os.path.exists(candidate):  # the path doesn't exist
            os.mkdir(candidate)  # create it
        current_path = candidate  # this is now our new path
    return current_path  # return the final path
```

Of course, you can use [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) instead to do all this for you. Either way, you should also check if you encounter a file along the way (as simple `os.path.exists()` won't suffice in all cases) and do error handling in case the user doesn't have permissions to create directories.

Also, don't use literal path separators as those differ from platform to platform (althouth CPython is usually smart enough to deal with platform differences).